# Inititialize alpha in LassoLarsCV and LassoCV in sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn

Is there a way to initialize (warm start) the value of `alpha` used in `LassoLarsCV` and `LassoCV`?
I understand that in `LassoCV` (why not in `LassoLarsCV`?) you can feed an alpha vector to test but I would like the algorithm to find the best `alpha` on its own. By initializing it  I save iterations because I have a rough idea of which alpha should be chosen.
For example, my `alphas` are typically at `1e-7` while the alpha sequence starts at `0.1`.

Answer (score 1):

`LassoCV` simply finds the "best" `alpha` among a pre-determined set using cross-validation.
If you know that it should be around `1e-7`, you can use a grid such as `np.geomspace(1e-8, 1e-6, 10)` as `alphas`.

On the other hand, `LassoLarsCV` will find "relevant" values of `alpha` automatically, meaning those at which the number of non-zero coefficients changes for the training set.
However, this does not mean that the "optimal" value of `alpha` for generalization is one of those.
If you do not want to specify the particular grid as proposed above, you could also first fit a `LassoLars` model with `alpha` parameter smaller than `1e-7`, filter the values in its `alphas_` to keep those around `1e-7` and pass them to `LassoCV`.
This would avoid including in the cross-validation the large values which you think are not going to be picked.